# Would it be forbidden to model a synagogue's design after the Beit Hamikdash?

Tags: halacha-theory, beis-hamikdash, synagogue, sin

The Beit Hamikdash has models. You can purchase them online if you so desire. That being said, those are purely models and are not used for anything beyond study/exhibition.

My question is whether it would be forbidden for a synagogue to be designed as a life-sized replica of the Beit Hamikdash. ***Specifically, just as a synagogue. In this scenario it would not be used for temple service activities. It would be purely a replica used as a synagogue.***

If a Jewish community decided to buy a large piece of land and model the design of their synagogue after the Beit Hamikdash, would it be considered a violation?

Seeing as how the temple could not function as the Beit Hamikdash since it wouldn't be in the correct location and wouldn't possess any of the internal necessities of the original, would there be any halachic considerations to such an idea?

Comment: There is no masorah to build synagogues in that way, so it may be objectionable on that basis.

Comment: Also, a Jew may be tempted to bring an offering there improperly, so it is a stumbling block before the blind.

Comment: Check out the current main synagogue in Shiloh

Comment: https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8107.htm#9